# Symfony - Azure Vault for DB password

Tags: php, azure, symfony, security

Is it possible to use Azure Vault to store MySQL DB credentials in Symfony?
Right now the credentials are stored in an .env file (encrypted) but there's a request to use Azure Key Vault instead. I've never heard about such a setup, is it possbile at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official PHP SDK for Azure keyvault, you could call the REST API - [`Set Secret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/setsecret/setsecret) to store the MySQL DB credentials directly as secrets in the keyvault. If you want to retrieve them, use [`Get Secret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret) to do that.

There are some prerequisites to call the rest apis.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

2.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

3.[Add the service principal to the keyvault access policy with correct secret permissions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal)

4.Use the [AAD client credential flow to get the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), then call the rest api.

Here is a [sample wrapper](https://github.com/bentaylorwork/php-azure-key-vault) of calling the rest apis, you could refer to it. See [Add secret](https://github.com/bentaylorwork/php-azure-key-vault/blob/master/examples/secret/addupdate.php) and [Get secret](https://github.com/bentaylorwork/php-azure-key-vault/blob/master/examples/secret/getlatestversion.php).

Comment: Thanks, looks like loads to do to achieve...not sure what exactly. As in, how this is more secure than having mysql user locked per IP? I mean if the app VM is compromised the attacker can get the db password regardless whether it's stored in a local config file or Azure vault (as he is on the trusted machine).

Comment: @GrumpyHat If so, both not safe, even if you use Azure VM, use [MSI(managed identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad) to access keyvault instead of uisng client secret(the safest way as I know), if the attacker can send the request in the machine, it is meanless, but I think azure VM is safer.;-)

Comment: That's interesting but still... if I have access to the app VM I could debug the php code and get the db connection string with the password in it... I am really struggling to understand the real benefit of this, except from the password management point of view. Unless that's what you meant?

Comment: @GrumpyHat If someone can access the VM, nothing will help. Except this, because the keyvault has the access policy, just the user/service principal added to it can access the keyvault, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault